# Dynamic corner Radius for landscape and portrait

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, cornerradius

I create UIView Extension with @IBInspectable to set corner radius but when I just rotate my device its not working properly

```
import UIKit
import Foundation

extension UIView {

@IBInspectable
var cornerRadius: CGFloat {
     get {
        return layer.cornerRadius
     }
     set {
        layer.cornerRadius = newValue
     }
   }
}
```

I took image view with following constraints
[image]

when I run app in portrait mode, output will be 
[image]

but its not work when i rotate my device 
[image]

Comment: Please check my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51652739/4061501) and could you please accept if its useful. So that it may helpful to someone else in future.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On rotation your view's size is changing, and previously applied cornerRadius becomes too big. You have to update your corner radius in layoutSubviews. Try this small class:

```
open class CircularView: UIView {
    @IBInspectable open var hasSquareCornerRadius: Bool = false {
        didSet {
            update()
        }
    }

    @IBInspectable open var cornerRadius: CGFloat = 0 {
        didSet {
            update()
        }
    }

    public var normalizedCornerRadius: CGFloat {
        return hasSquareCornerRadius ? bounds.height / 2 : cornerRadius
    }

    fileprivate func update() {
        layer.cornerRadius = cornerRadius
    }

    override open func layoutSubviews() {
        super.layoutSubviews()
        update()
    }
}
```

Set this class to your view in interface builder. If your view is square, check hasSquareCornerRadius to true in interface builder.

Answer (score 6):

Set the corner radius in  `layoutSubviews` method.

If you need the view in circular shape, set corner radius as it's half width/height.

```
view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.width / 2.0
```

Answer (score 3):

I can see in your screen Shot you are providing fixed corner radius

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYWSy.png)

also providing equal width or height to superview with multiplier so that when you rotate dimensions of UIView changed and you got this result.

you need to reset the corner radius of the view when orientation changes in `self.layoutSubviews()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can also just check programmatically if the device is horizontal or vertical and then just change the corner radius like Lal Krishna said

```
[[UIDevice currentDevice] beginGeneratingDeviceOrientationNotifications];

if ( ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] ==  UIDeviceOrientationPortrait) )
{
view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.width / 2.0
}
else if(([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIDeviceOrientationLandscapeRight) || ([[UIDevice currentDevice] orientation] == UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft))
{
view.layer.cornerRadius = view.frame.width / 2.0
}
```